# Creating SQL Tables based on ERD with two Weak entities

Tags: mysql, sql, erd, weak-entity

Struggling with this issue i have. have been given a ERD that looks like this:

[ERD Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Dkfi.png)

I am not sure how to join the 2nd Weak Entity (Charge Details)
Below is the SQL that is throwing an error when attempting to insert data.

```
CREATE TABLE Charge_Details
(
actid NUMBER NOT NULL,
empid NUMBER NOT NULL,
weekno NUMBER (2),
hrsworked NUMBER (4,1),
PRIMARY KEY (actid, empid, hrswork),
FOREIGN KEY (actid) REFERENCES ACTOR,
FOREIGN KEY (empid) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_DETAILS
);
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, silly mistake!

PRIMARY KEY (actid, empid, weekno)

thats what i need.